# Android Make a copy of a TableRow (widget) into a new TableRow (widget)

Tags: android, widget, tablerow, cloning, copying

I have seen similar questions posted for sqlite and C#.

But not for java. How do I go about copying an existing TableRow into a new TableRow?
I don't want to share any reference, I want the two widgets to be identical.
Could it be that java lacks this basic object copying functionality?
I think TableRows are not clonable, since Eclipse did not autocomplete when I tried to write `row.clone()`

Copying manually is not an option since there are a lot of fields to TableRow.

*Note: the "widget" in the title is to make it more generic for future searches*

Comment: Are you talking about the UI Designer or about the JAVA language? In the UI Designer one single row object is a placeholder for n rows. In Androids Java where's your row stored (database, Array,  ...)? Depending on that storage you use that copy/clone. Sorry if I mis-understand your question.

Comment: Why not just create the TableRow instance from scratch? Since you have created it in the first place, there must be some code in your app that can create it. So you could just call that code a second time.

Comment: I am talking about the TableRow widget that you add to a TableLayout. No database, UI only. I've seen that for sqlite there is an easy way to copy rows (it's a database, it would be disastrous not be able to copy records).

Comment: @Codo Codo, I need a generic way to do it, cannot rely on a specific row I created.

Comment: @ilomambo: But why? Can you explain the reasons? Copying UI widgets is always very problematic in all operating systems and all programming languages because each widget refers to windows, fonts, graphics buffers, screens, a parent widget etc. That's very different from a data row in SQL lite.

Comment: @Codo I change properties of individual TableRows, like background Drawable, typefaces, styles, text color, etc. Therefore I cannot just copy anyone row. I need to copy the row I want to copy with whatever properties it has.

Answer (score 0):

tableRow inherits from java.object however clone is not visible.  This should be posible using brute force.  A couple of options come to mind here.  One and probably the hardest but best method would be to implement the clonable interface in a sub class.

The other way would be to iterate through the children and deep copy them to a new table row.

Either way I dont envey what you have ahead of you.

Comment: I think I can recurse the hierarchy, but the body of work will be to ask for every child which intanceof it belongs to. I will have to ask for every possible type/class that might occur down the line. :::: I am really intrigued why the language did not provide for this, being OO and it being, I think reasonably, a needed feature.